# Javascript - Use data from previous request in a new request

Tags: javascript, axios, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to perform some API calls using Axios from the InLine editor of Dialogflow and cannot make it work, will you be able to help me?

```
function calc(agent) {
    axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=xxx')
      .then((result) => { 
             const Lat2 = result.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
             const Lng2 = result.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
      });
    const data = {
       "addresses": [
                {
                    "lat": Lat2,
                    "lon": Lng2,
                }
            ]
        };
    return axios.post('https://api.test.XXXX', data, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'YYYYYY'
        }})
    .then((result) => {
      const cant = result.data.total.amount;
            agent.add('This is ' + cant);
    });
    }
```

On the data constant, I'm unable to assign "lat" and "lon" to Lat2 and Lng2 variables.

Thank you.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that `Lat2` and `Lon2` are scoped inside the function passed to the first `.then()`. To access them, you either need to return them from that function and then chain another `.then()` afterwards, or you can move the later processing inside that same function.

### Promise chaining:

```
axios
  .get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=xxx')
  .then(result => {
    const Lat2 = result.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
    const Lng2 = result.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
    return { Lat2, Lng2 };
  })
  .then(({ Lat2, Lng2 }) => {
    const data = {
      addresses: [
        {
          lat: Lat2,
          lon: Lng2
        }
      ]
    };

    return axios.post('https://api.test.XXXX', data, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: 'YYYYYY'
      }
    });
  })
  .then(result => {
    const cant = result.data.total.amount;
    agent.add('This is ' + cant);
  });
```

### Later processing inside the same function:

```
axios
  .get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=xxx')
  .then(result => {
    const Lat2 = result.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
    const Lng2 = result.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

    const data = {
      addresses: [
        {
          lat: Lat2,
          lon: Lng2
        }
      ]
    };

    return axios
      .post('https://api.test.XXXX', data, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: 'YYYYYY'
        }
      })
      .then(result => {
        const cant = result.data.total.amount;
        agent.add('This is ' + cant);
      });
  });
```

Comment: Hello, the Later processing inside the same function code helped me a lot, thanks! The problem I have now is that the last piece of the code, "Agent.add" doesn´t work as it's not returning anything in the dialogflow agent...

Comment: Great! Abojt the agent issue, you might want to try that separately e.g. try adding the messages manually and if they work, move back to fetching them. Or try to isolate the problem more and ask another question on StackOverflow :)

Comment: Fixed :) It was all down to adding "Return" before the first axios. Thank you very much!

Comment: @JGN1987 By the way, be sure to click on the checkmark on the answer which you feel answered your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try async/await approach:

```
async function calc(agent) {
    const result = await axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=xxx') 
    const Lat2 = result.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
    const Lng2 = result.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
    const data = {
        "addresses": [
            {
                "lat": Lat2,
                "lon": Lng2,
            }
        ]
    };
    const result2 = await axios.post('https://api.test.XXXX', data, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'YYYYYY'
        }})
    const cant = result2.data.total.amount;
    agent.add('This is ' + cant);
}
```

Comment: missing `await` before `axios.post`

Comment: Yep! Thanks! Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Why don’t you make next call in the `then` clause of first call? These axios calls are async which means your `then` clause of first call will execute after the code written below it.
Refer to this article to understand how async calls work: https://medium.com/codebuddies/getting-to-know-asynchronous-javascript-callbacks-promises-and-async-await-17e0673281ee